# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: dom is not defined , babel

Tags: nodejs, webpack, reactjs, babel

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
export class V_admin extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
        super();
    }

      render() {
      return (
        <option>
           Hola mundo!
        </option>
    )
  }
}
```

Lanza error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: dom is not defined

Transpilando con **babel**:

```
dom(
    "option",
    null,
    "Hola mundo!"
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de hacer muchos tutoriales, en todos explican distinto, me sirvió como lo explican en este tutorial 
 medium.com/nodersec/webpack-babel-y-react-6b1f9353269 
es decir instalé esto

```
npm install --save react react-dom 
npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react webpack webpack-dev-server
```

e hice los imports como dice el tutorial y listo

Answer (score 0):

No sé el contexto de lo que estás creando, pero con ver tu código creo que debería ser así:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
export class V_admin extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <option>
           Hola mundo!
        </option>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<V_admin/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: He leido muchos foros y creo que es babel que no reconoce la importacion de react y react-dom, sin embargo sin solucion

Comment: es raro, yo he usado babel en otros foros y me permite hacer la importacion de react y react-dom sin problema. muestra tu configuracion.